How to get request body in middleware in Node.js
// routes/albums.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const albumUpload = require('../Middlewares/Multer'); // Use the updated multer config
const { uploadAlbum } = require('../Controller/Albumcontroller');


// Route to upload an album with metadata and photos
router.post('/upload',  (req, res, next) => {
    const { title } = req.body;  // Extract album title from request body

console.log("i am the body here:-", req.body) // gives output i am the body here:-{}
    const upload = albumUpload(title);  // Pass album title to middleware
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading files' });
      }
      next();
    });
  }, uploadAlbum



);
  
  module.exports = router;

I am trying to get the title from req.body as in the postman I am giving data in form-data.
but I am only getting Title = undefined and req.body = {}
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
require("dotenv").config();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

the above is the code snippet from my index.js

Ensure you added the express json middle ware to your application
const app = require('express');

app.use(
 express.json({
    limit: '20mb',
 }),
);


It's not working, I have also provided the index.js code snippet

By default, express doesn't parse multipart/form-data in req.body, so req.body remains empty i.e. {}. Since albumUpload is processing the incoming form-data, you need to access req.body after Multer processes it.
Do this.
//Route to upload an album with metadata and photos
router.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    const upload = albumUpload();
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading files' });
        }
        
        const { title } = req.body; // req.body is populated here
        console.log("i am the body here:-", req.body); // Should now show the form data
        next();
    });
}, uploadAlbum);

If other part of the code works as expected then above fixation will work.Try this and let me know.

What if I wanted to pass the title to the  upload function (multer function)
const upload = albumUpload(title);

@buildwithaniket, In that case you need to use busboy npm package as middleware which parse multipart/form-data by reading fields individually.
